# List of .properties files in Java applet

Tags: java, caching, jar, applet

Is there a way to get a list of properties files from inside applet without downloading jar file?

I can get the jar file using `getCodeBase()` and use it with jar reader, but this option is unacceptable for me since I have to download the file again.

I do not want to download the file again. I want to use the one that is already downloaded and running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to use the one I already downloaded..

So what is stopping you?  Note that an URL pointing back to the server for any resource that is already cached, will result in the JVM using the cached copy (even if the console indicates otherwise).

Comment: The problem was that i have disabled caching in java properties. This why i was always downloading the file. Thank you for leading me to a solution.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted, and thank you for stating what the problem is.  :)